# Karma running issue :Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine

I have installed Karma in my system and when I am running the script I am getting the issue.

```
C:\angularjs1-master\Ch 02\sp-blogger\scripts>test.bat
C:\angularjs1-master\Ch 02\sp-blogger\node_modules\policyfile\lib\server.js:254
Object.keys(process.EventEmitter.prototype).forEach(function proxy (key){
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\angularjs1-master\Ch 02\sp-blogger\node_modules\policyfile\lib\server.js:254:34)
```

Could not understand the error here. Kindly let me know if any dependency needs to be added or I need to do anything else.

Comment: Hello did you ever figure this issue out? Having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2):

So we couldn't upgrade the component that was using this and we had to downgrade our version of NodeJS to get these old legacy tests to run.

EventEmitter.prototype was removed in Node version 7 or 8 I think. We went back to 6 and it worked.